# Guide Text Not working when text is entered using another control

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a textbox used to enter the text by user, which guide-text which disappears when user starts to write. But when I use a dropdown & select a text from it, & this text is automatically entered in the textbox, the guide-text is not fading away.

Events I am using to fade the guide-text :

```
$('input, textarea').live('keydown', toggleLabel);
$('input, textarea').live('paste', toggleLabel);
```

On change of dropdown  :

```
$('.ui-discussion-text').change(function () {
    var oldText = $('.ui-discussion-input textarea').val();
    $('.ui-discussion-input textarea').val(oldText + " " + $(this).val());
});
```

Please help.

Comment: What does your `toggleLabel` function do? It's also worth noting that `live()` was deprecated in jQuery 1.7 in favour of `on()` and removed in 1.9.

Comment: We are using JQuery 1.6, so stuck with live. & toggleLabel function sets the guide text display to none.

Comment: Could you include sample html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little hard to say without seeing the rest of the code, but because you are changing code dynamically there isn't an event that will fire (I thought change might, but looked into it and realized it won't). Since you already have an onchange event for the dropdown, why not just call the toggleFunction at that point?

http://jsfiddle.net/spacebean/SvNUw

```
$('.ui-discussion-text').change(function () {
    var oldText = $('.ui-discussion-input textarea').val();
    $('.ui-discussion-input textarea').val(oldText + " " + $(this).val());
    toggleLabel();
});
```

Alternately, you can add a focus after you replace the text and set a listener for that:

http://jsfiddle.net/spacebean/SvNUw/2/

```
$('input, textarea').live('keydown paste focus', toggleLabel);

$('.ui-discussion-text').change(function () {
    var oldText = $('.ui-discussion-input textarea').val();
    $('.ui-discussion-input textarea').val(oldText + " " + $(this).val()).focus();

});
```

Or lastly, you can just add a trigger to the element after you copy the text, e.g.:
http://jsfiddle.net/spacebean/SvNUw/4/

```
$('input, textarea').live('keydown paste', toggleLabel);

$('.ui-discussion-text').change(function () {
    var oldText = $('.ui-discussion-input textarea').val();
    $('.ui-discussion-input textarea').val(oldText + " " + $(this).val()).trigger('paste');

});
```

And, as you can see, you don't need a separate line for each event type if they are all triggering the same function. Just add them separated by space like above.

Comment: This isnt helping me. Let me put my question in another way, What is the event triggered when we select the value from the dropdown & it is getting populated in textarea. it isnt the paste event, it isnt the focus event. I am not able to find out the event for which I can set the display to text as none.

Comment: Did you look at the working examples? There is no event when you copy the text in the background, but you can add one such as focus (as I did in the second example) when you do the copying, which will trigger the event.

Comment: I've added a third (probably simplest) option as well that should hopefully work for you.